# Putting Async functions into useEffect() hook in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm finishing up an app in which I want to hide my GoogleMap API key behind my secure API.  My intention is to call for the API key once I verify that I have an authenticated user.  The problem is that between the async calls, changes are not reflected with the state change.

This is what I am doing:

```
export default function App() {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(initialDateRange);
  const [formState, updateFormState] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [googleApiKey, setGoogleApiKey] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function updateAuth() {
      try {
        await checkUser();
        await getGoogleApiKey();
        await setAuthListener();
      } catch (error) {}
    }
    updateAuth();
  }, []);

  async function checkUser() {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      setUser(user);
      if (user !== authenticatedUser) {
        updateFormState(() => ({
          ...formState,
          authenticatedUser: user
        }));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async function getGoogleApiKey() {
    const googleApiUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH}apikey?googleapikey=true`; 
    try {
      console.log('USER_USER_USER', user);
      const apiKey = await fetch(googleApiUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
        }
      });
      console.log('GOT_GOOGLE_API_KEY', apiKey);
      setGoogleApiKey(apiKey);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async function setAuthListener() {
    Hub.listen('auth', (data) => {
      const event = data.payload.event;
      switch (data.payload.event) {
        case 'signOut':
          console.log('signing out...');
          console.log(event);
          updateFormState(() => ({
            ...formState,
            username: '',
            password: '',
            email: '',
            authenticatedUser: null
          }));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
USER_USER_USER null
App.js:78 TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInUserSession' of null
    at getGoogleApiKey (App.js:72)
    at updateAuth (App.js:42)
```

If this is the wrong paradigm, I'd appreciate any alternatives!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `setUser` is called, the `user` variable still holds old `user` information (`null` in this case), regardless of `async/await`:

```js
await checkUser();        // setUser(something) will not happen until next run
await getGoogleApiKey();  // user is still null
await setAuthListener();
```

One other choice would be to add another effect when `user` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
     getGoogleApiKey();
  }
}, [user]);
```

Or, call `getGoogleApiKey` with the parameter:

```
const user = await checkUser(); // return user
await getGoogleApiKey(user);
await setAuthListener();
```

Since the logic gets complex, I would suggest trying the [useReducer hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) because dispatch simplifies this complex back and forth scenarios.

Comment: I used `const user = await checkUser(); // return user` and it worked... pushing the key down to the Map components and rendering them conditionally if the api key is not null.  Thanks!